# Buscando dados em outro Schema do banco usando o createQuery

Tags: java, hibernate

No postgres, podemos buscar dados em vários schemas através do sql mesmo.
Fazendo assim:

```
SELECT * FROM meu_schema.minha_tabela
```

É possível fazer isso utilizando o `createQuery`?
Por padrão, minha aplicação está utilizando o schema public, mas queria fazer uma busca em outro schema em determinado método.

Algo parecido como:

```
Query query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT s FROM schema2.Simulacao s");
```

Answer (score 1):

Você deve criar um EntityManagerFactory e EntityManager  para cada esquema.

Ex.

```
javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory esquema1 = javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Esquema_1");
javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory esquema2 = javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Esquema_2");

EntityManager em1 = esquema1.createEntityManager();
EntityManager em2 = esquema2.createEntityManager();

Query query1 = em1.createQuery("SELECT s FROM Simulacao s");
Query query2 = em2.createQuery("SELECT s FROM Simulacao s");
```